# how can I get a regex that allows only 0000 or spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

how can I get a regex that allows only 0000 or spaces, but not both

examples:

1. 0000000000000000000   --> OK;
2. only spaces      --> OK;
3. 000000000     0000  --> Not Ok;
4. afads0000   00    0fd  --> Not Ok;

Comment: Something like (not sure about javascript version): `/^(0+|\s+)$/`

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, Thanks, now I realized that too :)

Comment: When you say "not both", does that also include leading and trailing spaces around the consecutive `0`s, like `"   0000   "`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^(?:0+| +)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
(?:    # Either match (but don't capture)...
 0+    # one or more zeroes
|      # or
 [ ]+  # one or more spaces
)      # End of non-capturing group (used to contain the alternation)
$      # End of string
```

Comment: `?:` means it's a non-capturing group

Comment: @F.Calderan: Right; I've improved my explanation accordingly.

Comment: @gdoron: Well, it *is* in the explanation ("One or more").

Comment: @TimPietzcker. not greedy is missing, isn't it?

Comment: @gdoron: What do you mean? It's irrelevant whether it's greedy or not. (And of course it *is* greedy.)

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** This answer only applies if you'll allow for leading and/or trailing spaces. The only example given in the question of spaces causing a fail, is where the space separates the `0` sequences.

*If not, you'll need a regex, like in [@Tim Pietzcker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10231993/1106925).*

---

You could do a *toNumber* conversion instead of a regex, since a string with only spaces will be converted to `0`, and leading/trailing spaces will be ignored.

Here I use the unary `+` operator to do the *toNumber* conversion.

```
if (+str === 0) {
   // pass
}
```

---

One caveat is that an empty string will also be converted to `0`. If that's not desired, you could first test the `.length`.

```
if (str.length && +str === 0) {
   // pass
}
```

---

```
"0000000000000000000"  // pass
"   000   "            // pass
"       "              // pass
"000000000 0000"       // fail
"afads0000 00 0fd"     // fail

""  // pass first solution, fail second solution
```

Comment: `Number("   000")` returns `0`, too, doesn't it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, perhaps I've interpreted that into the requirements incorrectly.

Comment: ...updated to include the caveat about leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `(0+)|( +)`, doesn't it?

Comment: This still matches the middle part of `abc000def`.